# MATLAB: how to plot a function with a matrix?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, matrix, plot

For an exercise at school, I'm trying to plot a function where the variable is a matrix.
The function is very simple: y=x^4
The matrix, x, is 0:0.01:20 so it has a range from 0 to 20, and there are 2000 between them.
My problem is, the scale of the x-axis is 0-2000, and not 0-20 as i'd suppose it to be.
According to the current graph: 1000^4=10000, while it should be: 10^4=10000.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `plot(x, x.^4)`, not `plot(x.^4)`

Comment: To expand on what @LuisMendo said: when you call [`plot(x)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) with one argument, the x-axis scale ranges from 1 to `length(x)`, so what you're seeing are the `y` values plotted against their indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is how it should be done. To limit the range of the x-axis and y-axis:  use these commands

```
ylim([minimumvalue maxvalue]);
xlim([minimumvalue maxvalue]);
```

Here is the answer to your question:

```
x =  0:0.01:20 ;
y =x.^4;

% plot function

plot(x,y);
title('My function')
xlabel('X-axis range')
xlim([0 20]) ![OUTPUT][1]
```